# Получение разницы во времени (минуты и секунды)

Tags: c#, datetime

Необходимо получить разницу во времени между двумя переменными, хранящими в себе информацию о минутах и секундах. Например date1 хранит в себе значение 01:15 (1 минута 15 секунд), переменная date2 хранит в себе значение 04:20 (4 минуты 20 секунд). Нужно найти date3 = date2 - date1. При этом информация о часах, днях, месяцах, годах никак не используется => не нужна. Я пытался использовать для решения задачи DateTime, но согласно информации из метаданных, DateTime имеет следующие конструкторы:

```
public DateTime(long ticks);
public DateTime(long ticks, DateTimeKind kind);
public DateTime(int year, int month, int day);
public DateTime(int year, int month, int day, Calendar calendar);
public DateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second);
public DateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, DateTimeKind kind);
<еще несколько вариаций>
public DateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond, Calendar calendar, DateTimeKind kind);
```

Конструктора принимающего значения только минут и секунд нет. Я прочитал об использовании своих форматов времени, но если я правильно понял, переменные DateTime все равно хранят в себе информацию о годах, часах и месяцах, а я лишь могу редактировать параметры вывода вроде

```
Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
```

Есть ли возможность использовать переменные DateTime необходимым мне образом, и сохранять в них информацию исключительно о минутах и секундах? Или мне нужно использовать какой то другой класс для этих целей? Отмечу при этом, что минуты и секунды, сохраняемые в переменных, не имеют никакого отношения к настоящему (т.е. создание DateTime now = DateTime.Now; не подходит).

Comment: *Конструктора принимающего значения только минут и секунд нет.* установите нули для отсутствующих компонентов.  Или не нули - но одинаково.

Comment: гляньте https://blog.rc21net.ru/csharp-date-and-time/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Вот решение
TimeSpan time1 = new TimeSpan(0,0,1,15);
TimeSpan time2 = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4, 15);
TimeSpan time3 = time1 - time2;
```